# Can I possibly be forgiven for doing this?

Tags: shirk, tawba, kufr, jahannam, imaan

Guys im really worried so a while ago I talked to an anonymous person on the internet and they may have committed shirk because of something I said but I only really thought about it now. I heard that in this situation I would carry the sin too but I don’t know who the person was because it was completely anonymous. If I repent and don’t do that again, is it possible that I could still be forgiven even if the person continues their sin? I really dont wanna be in hell forever because of this I don’t know what to do im really scared right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allah forgives all your sins so long as you are remorseful and regret what you have done.

The only way you'll be held accountable would be if you continued your connection with this person. As long as you cut your ties from this person, repent sincerely and never do anything like this again, Allah will forgive you.

It wouldn't make sense for Allah to continue punishing you for what you did, because if that was the case, you would indefinitely be lead to hell. Thankfully, Allah is the most forgiving and as long as you repent sincerely, all that haram that you were previously joined with will be cut off and you will not be dragged into hell for what you have done. You're human, Allah knows that which is why he's the most merciful.

Had you died in the state of shirk, yes Allah wouldn't have forgave you.

Comment: Thank you, so does that mean that I can be forgiven even if the person continues committing shirk because of me? I truly regret it now

Comment: @dlsj Yes you will be forgiven. It wouldn't make sense for Allah to continue to keep punishing you for something you did either on accident or even intentionally. But after turning back to Allah and changing your ways, all the haram ties you were associated with before have been cut off. If that wasn't the case, what would be the point of repentance? You would still be dragged to hell despite repenting if that was the case. Inshallah, now that you have reflected and admitted that you've done wrong, Allah is the most forgiving and loving and won't penalize you.

Comment: @dlsj you must warn them about shirk and its severity. But be careful. If they don't listen, leave them. Don't waste your time with them.

Comment: Ok thanks for answering but like im still a bit worried because of one thing: some of these people gave me their social media usernames but I never actually followed them or talked to them. Do I still need to tell them about this since I have their usernames and I could possibly dm them? Or can I just repent for myself without saying anything to them? I don’t really have contact to them so it would be a bit weird to suddenly talk to them, now im a little confused

Comment: Then leave them.

Comment: So I just shouldn’t say anything to them at all?

Comment: Well, if your ties have been cut, I don't see how they'll a part of your life anymore.

Comment: Okay, I was just worried because maybe I thought I should tell them so that they don’t commit a sin because of me but yeah I think I’ll just repent sincerely and not say anything

Comment: wait I just saw your comment with 'you must warn them about shirk' so do I have to reach out to them now? I’m sorry that I keep asking but I’m really scared

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you have done, if you really regret your sin ask Allah swt for firgiveness...ALLAH had promised us that he will forgive us but if we really regret that....it cant be like this....ya allah forgive me and then another day you will do the same sin that forgiveness will not be accepted by allah..but we know that Allah swt is so great and merciful inshallah he will forgive us